# How can I make my database Query more efficient?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to deploy my rails app but my herokuapp makes an error when I run it. But in my ubuntu, when I run my rails app, it runs smoothly.

How can I make my query more efficient? I think it has something to do with the query, that's why my herokuapp is making an error.

In my **events_controller**

```
@forw = Forward.select(:user_id).where(:doc_id => params[:id])
@users = User.where.not(:id => "#{@user.id}").where.not(:id => @forw)
@sent = User.where.not(:id => "#{@user.id}").where(:id => @forw)
#line #41
@status = Forward.select(:status).where(user_id: @sent.ids).where(doc_id: params[:id])
```

And it causes this error

```
2018-07-13T06:06:59.283437+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-07-13T06:06:59.283386 #4] FATAL -- : [4391812e-d824-4a3d-b87f-28a231dc54cc] ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: bigint = text
2018-07-13T06:06:59.283438+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...sers" WHERE ("users"."id" != $1) AND "users"."id" IN (SELECT...
2018-07-13T06:06:59.283440+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2018-07-13T06:06:59.283441+00:00 app[web.1]: HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
2018-07-13T06:06:59.283443+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" != $1) AND "users"."id" IN (SELECT "forwards"."user_id" FROM "forwards" WHERE "forwards"."doc_id" = $2)):
2018-07-13T06:06:59.283486+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-07-13T06:06:59.283441 #4] FATAL -- : [4391812e-d824-4a3d-b87f-28a231dc54cc]
2018-07-13T06:06:59.283544+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-07-13T06:06:59.283498 #4] FATAL -- : [4391812e-d824-4a3d-b87f-28a231dc54cc] app/controllers/events_controller.rb:41:in `forward'
```

In my **logins_controller**

```
@forwards = Forward.select(:doc_id).where(:user_id => "#{@user.id}").where(:status => 'FORWARDED')
@received = Document.where(:id => @forwards)
```

And it causes this error

```
2018-07-13T06:09:42.579716+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-07-13T06:09:42.579651 #4]  INFO -- : [f55de38f-3744-4cec-a2c4-5317efa61462] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 17ms (ActiveRecord: 7.9ms)
2018-07-13T06:09:42.580566+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-07-13T06:09:42.580498 #4] FATAL -- : [f55de38f-3744-4cec-a2c4-5317efa61462]
2018-07-13T06:09:42.580619+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-07-13T06:09:42.580563 #4] FATAL -- : [f55de38f-3744-4cec-a2c4-5317efa61462] ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: bigint = text
2018-07-13T06:09:42.580621+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...uments".* FROM "documents" WHERE "documents"."id" IN (SELECT...
2018-07-13T06:09:42.580623+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2018-07-13T06:09:42.580625+00:00 app[web.1]: HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
2018-07-13T06:09:42.580627+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "documents".* FROM "documents" WHERE "documents"."id" IN (SELECT "forwards"."doc_id" FROM "forwards" WHERE "forwards"."user_id" = $1 AND "forwards"."status" = $2)):
2018-07-13T06:09:42.580877+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-07-13T06:09:42.580818 #4] FATAL -- : [f55de38f-3744-4cec-a2c4-5317efa61462]     190:                             %th Description
2018-07-13T06:09:42.580880+00:00 app[web.1]: [f55de38f-3744-4cec-a2c4-5317efa61462]     191:                             %th Options
2018-07-13T06:09:42.580881+00:00 app[web.1]: [f55de38f-3744-4cec-a2c4-5317efa61462]     192:                         %tbody{:align => "center"}
2018-07-13T06:09:42.580883+00:00 app[web.1]: [f55de38f-3744-4cec-a2c4-5317efa61462]     193:                           - @received.each do |document|
2018-07-13T06:09:42.580885+00:00 app[web.1]: [f55de38f-3744-4cec-a2c4-5317efa61462]     194:                             %tr
2018-07-13T06:09:42.580886+00:00 app[web.1]: [f55de38f-3744-4cec-a2c4-5317efa61462]     195:                               %td= document.name
2018-07-13T06:09:42.580888+00:00 app[web.1]: [f55de38f-3744-4cec-a2c4-5317efa61462]     196:                               %td= document.author_name
2018-07-13T06:09:42.580923+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-07-13T06:09:42.580872 #4] FATAL -- : [f55de38f-3744-4cec-a2c4-5317efa61462]
2018-07-13T06:09:42.580973+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-07-13T06:09:42.580924 #4] FATAL -- : [f55de38f-3744-4cec-a2c4-5317efa61462] app/views/logins/dashboard.html.haml:193:in `_app_views_logins_dashboard_html_haml__4338535734076852815_41972620'
```

In my **folders_controller**

```
@doc_type = params[:doc_type]
@doc_id = Document.select(:id).distinct.where(doc_type: params[:doc_type])
#line #48
@doc_year = Event.find_by_sql("SELECT DISTINCT strftime('%Y', event_date) as dates FROM events e JOIN documents d ON  e.event_date = d.date_modified where d.doc_type = '#{@doc_type}'")
```

And it causes this error

```
2018-07-13T06:08:01.901994+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-07-13T06:08:01.901927 #4]  INFO -- : [28c1cc51-c582-4fcb-8665-62410aa26ef5] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 3.9ms)
2018-07-13T06:08:01.902614+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-07-13T06:08:01.902545 #4] FATAL -- : [28c1cc51-c582-4fcb-8665-62410aa26ef5]
2018-07-13T06:08:01.902675+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-07-13T06:08:01.902609 #4] FATAL -- : [28c1cc51-c582-4fcb-8665-62410aa26ef5] ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function strftime(unknown, date) does not exist
2018-07-13T06:08:01.902677+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT strftime('%Y', event_date) as dates FROM eve...
2018-07-13T06:08:01.902679+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2018-07-13T06:08:01.902681+00:00 app[web.1]: HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
2018-07-13T06:08:01.902683+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT DISTINCT strftime('%Y', event_date) as dates FROM events e JOIN documents d ON  e.event_date = d.date_modified where d.doc_type = 'Letter'):
2018-07-13T06:08:01.902721+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-07-13T06:08:01.902671 #4] FATAL -- : [28c1cc51-c582-4fcb-8665-62410aa26ef5]
2018-07-13T06:08:01.902773+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-07-13T06:08:01.902724 #4] FATAL -- : [28c1cc51-c582-4fcb-8665-62410aa26ef5] app/controllers/folders_controller.rb:48:in `folder_year'
```

**MODELS**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :document, optional: true
  validates :event_date, presence: true
  validates :event_type, presence: true
  validates :doc_id, presence: true
end

class Forward < ApplicationRecord
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :doc_id, presence: true
end

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :author
  has_many :event

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :doc_type, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :location, presence: true
end

class Request < ApplicationRecord
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
      user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
      user.emailadd = auth.info.email
      user.save!
    end
  end

  validates :emailadd,
   uniqueness: true, presence: true,
   format: {
     message: 'domain must be @up.edu.ph', with: /\A[\w+-.]+@up.edu.ph\z/i}
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
end
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @Subash when I deploy my railsapp and I run it, the herokuapp causes an error, while it is working properly in my ubuntu. I think it has something to do with my query.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @JustinWorkman I added the error

Comment: You can use [MySQL join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)...

Comment: @MrShemek In which line should I do that?

Comment: Please add your model's definitions (I am interested in relations, like `belongs_to`, `has_one/many`). It will be useful.

Comment: @MrShemek I put the models already

Comment: What database (engine and version) do you use on your Ubuntu machine and what do you try to use on Heroku?

Comment: According to my gemfile, the development is using sqlite3 while the production is using postgresql

Answer (score 2):

Let's start from **logins_controller**

```
@forwards = Forward.select(:doc_id).where(:user_id => "#{@user.id}").where(:status => 'FORWARDED')
@received = Document.where(:id => @forwards)
```

1. If you are not using `@forwards` anywhere except `where` for the document, then you do not have to use an instance variable to define it. In fact, you do not have to define it at all. Use `joins` to connect multiple tables into one and call the query on it.
2. I am not sure why you do something like this: `"#{@user.id}"` instead of `@user.id`.
3. You can put multiple conditions in a single `where`

Improved code:

```
@received = Document.joins("LEFT JOIN forwards on forwards.doc_id = documents.id").where(forwards: {user_id: @user.id, status: 'FORWARDER'})
```

Comment: I have done that. But I still need to change the other queries

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I have shown you how to do that. Now, read a little bit about joins and implement your own solution.

Comment: @tougherjan  if you just add `has_many :forwards` to `Document` then this could be simplified to `Document.joins(:forwards).where(forward: { status: 'FORWARDED', user_id: @user.id}).distinct`

Comment: @engineersmnky of course there are relations missing but I assumed that there is a reason for not adding them.